# Copy a range of adjacent Columns from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: copy

I am trying to copy adjacent columns U:W from sheet1 to sheet2 with the following code and don’t work...what is wrong????

```
Dim rngUW As Range
Set rngUW = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("U2:W2"), Range("U1:W1").End(xlDown))
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
```

Comment: Hi again Vaggelis, I think you need to put in a bit more effort with this question before posting it here. Start with this: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error message? If yes, which one? Are you using `Option Explicit`? If not, read up on it here: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html

Comment: Hi DirtyDeffy thank you for your response, I don’t have option Explicit on and when I run the code I have ‘’Run-Time error 1004 Application defiend or oblect defined error’’ when I press debug the Set line turn yellow

Comment: Sorry i correct already the rnzUW and the problem stay the same

Comment: DirtyDeffy I found it i was focus on sheet2 i have to activate sheet1 first..!!!!!

Comment: Thats great - good job :) Now consider making your question QA style if you think it would be valuable to others. Otherwise you might want to delete the question :)