# find and replace using WildCard

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column range (stored as text) where I have to replace second last digit from 7 to 5 for only cells ending in "-fsa". Here is an example

Find

```
52881871-fsa
```

Replace

```
52881851-fsa
```

I tried using wildcard, however it only works in find function but doesn't work in replace function.

Thank You for the help!

I used following in my code, the find does what's asked but replace doesn't

```
Selection.Replace What:=("??????7?-fsa"), Replacement:=("??????5?-fsa"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: `What:=("??????7?-fsa)` is missing the closing quote `What:=("??????7?-fsa")`

Comment: thanks, sorry that was a typo on my part, however the code doesn't still produce the intended result.

Comment: Thank you PEH, that works !! however it only does one value at a time, is there way to do for whole column ? e.g all in Column A, do I have to put a counter loop ?

Comment: Do some research on how to use `.FindNext` or see [Find and FindNext for Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380490/find-and-findnext-for-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards only in the find pattern but not in the replace pattern. You need to use `Selection.Find` instead of `.Replace`. And then split the found string to replace the `7` with a `5`.

```
Dim FoundAt As Range
Set FoundAt = Selection.Find(What:=("??????7?-fsa"), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
    False)
    
If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then
    FoundAt.Value = Left$(FoundAt.Value, 6) & "5" & Right$(FoundAt.Value, 5)
End If
```

Alternatively you can do that with regular expressions: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)