# VBA .FindNext Not finding nextfind

Tags: excel, vba, find

When I step through my line and try to find my .FindNext "findLot" it shows nothing but I know for a fact there is another identical # in column 3 which is equal to rng2.

```vb
    '''''''''''''''''' START OF WEIGHT LOOP '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If UserResponse = "Weight" Then
        Dim arr2 As Variant
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim rng2 As Range
        Dim rng3 As Range
        Dim findItem As Range
        Dim findLot As Range
        Dim findBin As Range
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim numberTimes As Integer
        Dim firstCell As String
        Dim firstLot As String
        Dim firstBin As String

        Call TurnOnStuff
        UserWeight = InputBox("Enter Max Weight: ")
        Call TurnOffStuff
        arr1 = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        arr2 = Cells(6, 6).CurrentRegion
        x = 2
        For i = LBound(arr2, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr2, 1)
            If Cells(i, 2).value Like "*857*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[G]*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[M]*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[C]*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[L]*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[Z]*" Or Cells(i, 2).value Like "*[O]*" Then
      

            Else
                numberTimes = 1
                itemName = arr2(i, 1)
                itemWeight = arr2(i, 2)
                Set rng1 = Columns(2)
                Set findItem = rng1.Find(What:=itemName)
                If Not findItem Is Nothing Then
                    Do
                        firstCell = findItem.Address
                        If Cells(findItem.Row, 4).value * itemWeight < UserWeight And Cells(findItem.Row, 4).value * itemWeight <> 0 And Cells(findItem.Row, 3) <> cellLot Then
                            cellLot = Cells(findItem.Row, 3).value
                            Set rng2 = Columns(3)
                            Set findLot = rng2.Find(What:=cellLot)
                            If Not findLot Is Nothing Then
                                firstLot = findLot.Address
                                Do
                                    If Cells(findLot.Row, 4).value * itemWeight < UserWeight And Cells(findLot.Row, 4).value * itemWeight <> 0 And Cells(findLot.Row, 2).value = itemName Then
                                        Set rng3 = Columns(10)
                                        Set findBin = rng3.Find(What:=itemName)
                                        If Not findBin Is Nothing Then
                                            firstBin = findBin.Address
                                            Do
                                                If Cells(findBin.Row, 3) = cellLot Then
                                                    rowNumber = findBin.Row + numberTimes
                                                    Range("I" & rowNumber & ": L" & rowNumber).Insert
                                                    Cells(findLot.Row, 1).Resize(1).Copy
                                                    Cells(rowNumber, 9).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                                    Cells(findLot.Row, 2).Resize(1).Copy
                                                    Cells(rowNumber, 10).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                                    Cells(findLot.Row, 3).Resize(1).Copy
                                                    Cells(rowNumber, 11).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                                    Cells(findLot.Row, 4).Resize(1).Copy
                                                    Cells(rowNumber, 12).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                                    x = x + 1
                                                    numberTimes = numberTimes + 1
                                                    Exit Do
                                                End If
                                                Set findBin = rng3.FindNext(findBin)
                                            Loop While firstBin <> findBin.Address
                                        Else
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 1).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 9).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 2).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 10).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 3).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 11).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 4).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 12).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            x = x + 1
                                        End If
                                    ElseIf Cells(findLot.Row, 4).value * itemWeight > UserWeight And Cells(findLot.Row, 2).value = itemName Then
                                        Set rng = Columns(10)
                                        Set findBin = rng.Find(itemName)
                                        If Not findBin Is Nothing Then
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 1).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 9).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 2).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 10).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 3).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 11).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            Cells(findLot.Row, 4).Resize(1).Copy
                                            Cells(x, 12).Offset.PasteSpecial
                                            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                                            x = x + 1
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    ''''''''''''''''''' NOT WORKING  '''''''''''''''''''

                                    Set findLot = rng2.FindNext(findLot)
                                    If findLot Is Nothing Then
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop While firstLot <> findLot.Address
                                > > End If

                                ''''''''''''''''''' Implement Different Lot Scenario ''''''''''''''''''''''''

                                ''''''''''''  NEEDS DONE '''''''''''''''

                            End If

                            Set findItem = rng1.FindNext(findItem)
                        Loop While firstCell1 <> findItem.Address
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            End If
```

I do not know what else to try as everything looks correct to me. And help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I believe you're getting tripped up by not properly setting `findLot` prior to the `.FindNext` statement. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381398/4717755)

Comment: So what am I missing cause I still don't see it.

Comment: You should probably check your assumptions. This code is a bit hard to read - there are so many levels of IFs and DO WHILEs that its mainly impossible to follow. Probably to test your find/find next I would create a separate small subroutine just to do the finds and find nexts - see if your assumptions are correct about what you are finding. Hard to suggest a lot because it's hard to follow this code.

Comment: Yeah well I'm trying to cross reference two data sets one has two columns item# and item weight, and the other is bin location, item#, lot#, and QTY. So I start with the for loop to grab the first item# in the weight table, then I use the finditem to find that item in the other table. Once I find that item I use a findlot to store that lot# and loop through the second table that way because we have items with different lot#'s. Once I find that I am creating a new table with items under userweight weight followed by item over userweight. And they are sorted by their item# and Lot#.

Comment: I already created a macro that loops through arrays to get my results and it works but it takes like 30minutes to run because we have 30,000 locations and over 7,000 item#'s. So I'm trying to recreate it using Find, findnext to speed up the runtime

Comment: I think I found my problem. I don't think you are able to use find/findnext on top of each other. So I'm trying to find the item, then the lot. So once I loop through the lots and come back to the item it shows nothing because I think the lot/find next canceled out the item/find next... any thoughts?

Comment: If you're using arrays and found that to be slow (no surprise), try using one or more `Dictionary`. After initially building the dictionary once, lookups are immediate (no looping at all).

Comment: *I don't think you are able to use find/findnext on top of each other* yes this is correct.